# z3Exception: file access error

Tags: z3

I have been experimenting with z3 java bindings and have coded the following : https://pastebin.com/x1Tcw10Z . I get the following error and have no clue how to solve it.

com.microsoft.z3.Z3Exception: file access error

```
at com.microsoft.z3.Native.parseSmtlib2File(Native.java:3665)
at com.microsoft.z3.Context.parseSMTLIB2File(Context.java:2584)
at JavaExample1.smt2FileTest(JavaExample1.java:57)
at JavaExample1.main(JavaExample1.java:144)
```

Note : The file is getting converted to the string alright and there is no issue there.

Pls help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `p.smt2FileTest(contents);`, i.e. `ctx.parseSMTLIB2File` will get the contents of the file, not just the name of the file. You can use [`parseSMTLIB2String`](http://z3prover.github.io/api/html/classcom_1_1microsoft_1_1z3_1_1_context.html#abacc1fe2a9e8902dfaa63575717229b4) instead.